# Efficient method to get one number, which can't be generated from any XORing combination

Tags: algorithm, xor

If there is any number in the range [0 .. 2<sup>64</sup>] which can not be generated by any XOR composition of one or more numbers from a given set, is there a efficient method which prints at least one of the unreachable numbers, or terminates with the information, that there are no unreachable numbers?
Does this problem have a name?  Is it similar to another problem or do you have any idea, how to solve it?

Comment: No, the numbers can't be repeated, would this make a difference – except for the number 0 (a xor a)?

Comment: @ChristianAmmer You are right, the only difference will be that you can always make 0 with the repeats.

Comment: Exactly, my point. If numbers cannot be repeated, you got your answer. `0` is a number that cannot be generated by any combination of `XOR`.

Comment: unless he got a number twice. When `a == b` then `a XOR b = 0`.

Comment: @noMAD: Sure it can be generated, e.g. `10 XOR 01 XOR 11 = 00`

Comment: Yea, Anony proved it wrong. My bad!! :)

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: I have a point here. I might be wrong. But what you did gave me an idea. According to what you wrote, you can get `0` with some combination of numbers. Now, we know that `Anything XOR 0` is `The number itself`. Hence, can't we conclude that any number can be achieved even though we use that number for achieving it. (I might need some sleep)

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. You'd need to have everything already before. XOR 0 obviously doesn't get you anything *new*, so being able to build 0 doesn't help much.

Comment: Do you need to be able to say *which* numbers cannot be generated? Or is it enough to know you can or cannot generate all?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: For my needs, it would be enough to know if there is no number which can not be generated, or if there are such numbers, one would be enough to be printed.

Comment: Essentially I was thinking along the lines of rap musics answer, gaussian elimination. See his excellent answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each number can be treated as a vector in the vector space (Z/2)^64 over Z/2. You basically want to know if the vectors given span the whole space, and if not, to produce one not spanned (except that the span always includes the zero vector – you'll have to special case this if you really want one or more). This can be accomplished via Gaussian elimination.

Over this particular vector space, Gaussian elimination is pretty simple. Start with an empty set for the basis. Do the following until there are no more numbers. (1) Throw away all of the numbers that are zero. (2) Scan the lowest bits set of the remaining numbers (lowest bit for `x` is `x & ~(x - 1)`) and choose one with the lowest order bit set. (3) Put it in the basis. (4) Update all of the other numbers with that same bit set by XORing it with the new basis element. No remaining number has this bit or any lower order bit set, so we terminate after 64 iterations.

At the end, if there are 64 elements, then the subspace is everything. Otherwise, we went fewer than 64 iterations and skipped a bit: the number with only this bit on is not spanned.

To special-case zero: zero is an option if and only if we never throw away a number (i.e., the input vectors are independent).

---

Example over 4-bit numbers

Start with 0110, 0011, 1001, 1010. Choose 0011 because it has the ones bit set. Basis is now {0011}. Other vectors are {0110, 1010, 1010}; note that the first 1010 = 1001 XOR 0011.

Choose 0110 because it has the twos bit set. Basis is now {0011, 0110}. Other vectors are {1100, 1100}.

Choose 1100. Basis is now {0011, 0110, 1100}. Other vectors are {0000}.

Throw away 0000. We're done. We skipped the high order bit, so 1000 is not in the span.

Comment: would you clarify your answer with sample? I think each of your steps takes exponential time (respect to your step), so having 64 step is not amazing (can cause to 2^64 bit operation).

Comment: +1: amazing and spot on.  @SaeedAmiri Gaussian elimination is a well-known algorithm (in linear algebra), with running time O(n^3).

Comment: In this particular case, it's O(n), since the constant 64^2 (of which 64 is bitwise parallel) is absorbed by the big-O.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will read and learn something about vectors, the basis and recall the gaussian elimination, to completely understand.

Answer (score 3):

As *rap music* points out you can think of the problem as finding a base in a vector space. However, it is not necessary to actually solve it completely, just to find if it is possible to do or not, and if not: give an example value (that is a binary vector) that can not be described in terms of the supplied set.

**This can be done in O(n^2)** in terms of the size of the input set. This should be compared to **Gauss elimination which is O(n^3)**, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination.

64 bits are no problem at all. With the example python code below 1000 bits with a set with 1000 random values from 0 to 2^1000-1 takes about a second.

Instead of *performing* Gauss elimination it's enough to find out if we can rewrite the matrix of all bits on triangular form, such as: (for the 4 bit version:)

```
 original        triangular
 1110 14         1110 14
 1011 11          111  7
  111  7           11  3
   11  3            1  1
    1  1            0  0
```

The solution works like this: First all original values with the same most significant bit are places together in a list of lists. For our example:

```
 [[14,11],[7],[3],[1],[]]
```

The last empty entry represents that there were no zeros in the original list. Now, take a value from the first entry and replace that entry with a list containing only that number:

```
 [[14],[7],[3],[1],[]]
```

and then store the xor of the kept number with all the removed entries at the right place in the vector. For our case we have 14^11 = 5 so:

```
 [[14],[7,5],[3],[1],[]]
```

The trick is that we do not need to scan and update all other values, just the values with the same most significant bit.

Now process the item 7,5 in the same way. Keep 7, add 7^5 = 2 to the list:

```
 [[14],[7],[3,2],[1],[]]
```

Now 3,2 leaves [3] and adds 1 :

```
 [[14],[7],[3],[1,1],[]]
```

And 1,1 leaves [1] and adds 0 to the last entry allowing values with no set bit:

```
 [[14],[7],[3],[1],[0]]
```

If in the end the vector contains at least one number at each vector entry (as in our example) the base is complete and any number fits.

Here's the complete code:

```
# return leading bit index ir -1 for 0.
# example 1 -> 0
# example 9 -> 3
def leadbit(v):
    # there are other ways, yes...
    return len(bin(v))-3 if v else -1

def examinebits(baselist,nbitbuckets):
    # index 1 is least significant bit. 
    # index 0 represent the value 0    
    bitbuckets=[[] for x in range(nbitbuckets+1)]  
    for j in baselist:
        bitbuckets[leadbit(j)+1].append(j)   
    for i in reversed(range(len(bitbuckets))):
        if bitbuckets[i]:
            # leave just the first value of all in bucket i
            bitbuckets[i],newb=[bitbuckets[i][0]],bitbuckets[i][1:]
            # distribute the subleading values into their buckets
            for ni in newb: 
                q=bitbuckets[i][0]^ni
                lb=leadbit(q)+1
                if lb:
                    bitbuckets[lb].append(q)
                else:
                    bitbuckets[0]=[0]
        else:
            v=2**(i-1) if i else 0
            print "bit missing: %d. Impossible value: %s == %d"%(i-1,bin(v),v)
            return (bitbuckets,[i])    
    return (bitbuckets,[])
```

Example use: (8 bit)

```
import random
nbits=8
basesize=8
topval=int(2**nbits)
# random set of values to try:
basel=[random.randint(0,topval-1) for dummy in range(basesize)]
bl,ii=examinebits(basel,nbits)
```

`bl` is now the triangular list of values, up to the point where it was not possible (in that case). The missing bit (if any) is found in ii[0].

For the following tried set of values: `[242, 242, 199, 197, 177, 177, 133, 36]` the triangular version is:

```
base value: 10110001 177
base value:  1110110 118
base value:   100100 36
base value:    10000 16
first missing bit: 3 val: 8
( the below values where not completely processed )
base value:       10 2
base value:        1 1
base value:        0 0
```

The above list were printed like this:

```
for i in range(len(bl)):
    bb=bl[len(bl)-i-1]
    if ii and len(bl)-ii[0] == i:
        print "example missing bit:" ,(ii[0]-1), "val:", 2**(ii[0]-1)
        print "( the below values where not completely processed )"
    if len(bb):
        b=bb[0]
        print ("base value: %"+str(nbits)+"s") %(bin(b)[2:]), b
```

Comment: Thanks for your method with the triangular matrix and the given code. I will try it and need some time to fully understand. Just one question to your example above: first you wrote the numbers `14, 11, 7, 3, 1`, later (in the list of lists) the numbers are `14, 11, 7, 4, 2`. Why 3 becomes 4 and 1 becomes 2?

Comment: @ChristianAmmer, Welcome - about the example, you found a typo which then propagated. I now updated that.